# MySQL Foreign Keys ALTER statement

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL 5.6.16
Two tables. Altering Table 1 to have a foreign key to Table 2's primary key. SQL Error 1215.

If I drop Table 1 and incorporate the foreign key constraint into the build, it accepts the constraint just fine. Only altering the tables after creation causes a problem.

Any ideas? Below are two attempts at writing the alter statement, followed by the creation script.

```
    ALTER TABLE c_users ADD FOREIGN KEY fk_user_prof_position_tid(professional_position_tid) REFERENCES d_taxonomy(tid);
    ALTER TABLE c_users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user_prof_position_tid FOREIGN KEY (professional_position_tid) REFERENCES d_taxonomy(tid);

    CREATE TABLE c_users (
    user_id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Primary, auto-generated key',
    professional_position_tid INT(11),
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    CREATE INDEX i_user_id ON c_users (user_id) USING BTREE;

    CREATE TABLE d_taxonimy (
    tid INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (tid)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
    CREATE INDEX i_tid ON d_taxonimy (tid) USING BTREE;
```

Comment: `show engine innodb status` will have more details about the Fk error buried about 1/2 way down the output. it'll tell you exactly why the alter was rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typos:

```
ALTER TABLE [...snip...] REFERENCES d_taxonomy(tid);
                                         ^----

CREATE TABLE d_taxonimy (
                    ^----
```

Plus, if you're running the statements in that order, you can't alter a table which doesn't exist yet, or create a foreign key when the foreign field/table don't exist yet either.

Comment: Definitely ran the alter statements after creation. Fixing the typo works, and makes me feel about as smart as a rock. Thanks!